# Getting "400 Bad Request" and "invalid_grant" message with "Net::Google::Drive::Simple"

Tags: perl, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm using `[Net::Google::Drive::Simple][1]` to fetch a document from the web and place it on my Google Drive. The script was working fine until I recently started getting the following error: `Token refresh failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/OAuth/Cmdline.pm line 76`.

Printing out the headers from the response from Google shows the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 08:32:13 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Ranges: none
Server: GSE
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"
Client-Date: Mon, 24 Oct 2016 08:32:13 GMT
Client-Peer: 2607:f8b0:4006:80e::200d:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=accounts.google.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First thing to check:**

Your server’s clock is not in sync with [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). (Solution: check the server time if its incorrect fix it. )

**Second thing to check:**

Your refresh token is not valid you need a new one.   Authenticate your code again.

Possible reasons for a refresh token to no longer work.

1. User revoked it in their Google account.
2. Refresh token hasn't been used to get a new access token in six months.
3. Maximum number of refresh tokens for a user reached: If a user authenticates your application you get a refresh token associated with the user who authenticated it.  If the user runs it again and you get a second refresh token.  You can have up to 25 outstanding refresh tokens for each user at which point the first one given will expire and no longer work.  This is why its important to always save the most resent refresh token for a user.

Comment: I did check the clock. It is spot on.

When you say "authenticate your code again" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Oauth2, pop up the window ask for access.   You are using a refresh token where did you get it? Your script needed permission to write to your Google drive account.

Comment: This is a perl script doing the work which retrieves the secret from a .yml file on my server. When I look at my Google console, I can see the credentials for the Google Drive API and everything matches up with what is in my .yml file.

Comment: We are not talking about a secret here or the project on Google Developer console.  We are talking about how you authenticated your script to write to your person Google Drive account.   You must be using a refresh token or you wouldn't be seeing "Token refresh failed"  where is the refresh token and how did you get it?

Comment: Also, I can see the .yml file is getting updated with latest access token as evidenced by the timestamp of the .yml file.

Comment: The Net::Google::Drive::Simple perl module is supposed to handle this all for me, from what I understand. The .yml file contains the refresh token.

Comment: Indeed it does.  However if the Refresh token is no longer valid you will need to authenticate the code again and get a new Refresh token.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Net-Google-Drive-Simple-0.12/lib/Net/Google/Drive/Simple.pm  check the section getting started.   "It also contains a refresh token that this library uses to get a new access token transparently when the old one is about to expire."

Comment: Ok, I see there is a script I'm supposed to run. It starts up a server. Unfortunately, I'm having trouble connecting to it but that's another problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK, I was able to connect to the server and log into google and the .yml file was updated and everything works again. Thanks again!